# Menu item addClass disappears when i arrive at new page

Tags: jquery, navigation, superfish

Hi i am using superfish menu, and are relatively new to jquery, when i use addClass to add a class to a menu item, it adds the class but when the new page loads it disappears.
So to be really clear if i am at the **home page** and want to go to the **sales page**, i would liken the sales menu item to have the active class when i arrive here is what i have

**here is my menu**

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled" id="navmain">
<li><a href="/index.php">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/sales/">SALES</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/clothing/">CLOTHING</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/accessories/">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
<li><a href="/cart.php">CART</a></li>
<li><a href="/wishlist.php">WISHLIST</a></li>
<li><a href="/contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
<li><a href="/aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Here is my jquery**

```
$('#navbar ul li').click(function(){
    $('#navbar li a').removeClass("active");
    $('#navbar li a').addClass("active");
    });
```

Am i doing this correctly?

I have also tried this to no avail

```
$('#navbar ul li').click(function(e){
    $('#navbar li a').removeClass("active");
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: The 'sales' page is a *different page to* the 'home' page; the JavaScript on the *first* cannot affect the presentation, behaviour or styling of the content of the *second* (this assumes you're loading an entirely new page, obviously).

Comment: i have also tried$('#navbar ul li').click(function(e){
    $('#navbar li a').removeClass("active");
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    });

Answer (score 0):

The change you are making doesn't persist when you change pages or reload the page. You might be able to set a variable and then add the class based on that. I recently had to hack something similar together and this is what I came up with.

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.redirect == "/invite#outstanding"){
        newValue = true
    }
    if (data.redirect) {
        window.location.href = data.redirect;

        if (newValue == true) {
            document.location.reload(true)
        }
    }
```